# Android Horizontal Sliding List View over Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, linked-list

I came across this application called Housing which has a list view over the map and as and when we move the across the items of the list the marker of the map as well corresponding to the location of that item on the map.

[image]

Is there any Library that allows us to do that? or any starting point on how to have the list view on top of the MAP like that?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3087   here is a library , you can check .    or if you find any better library , pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview is able to do that

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: looks like its a nice concept. i will read about RecyclerViews :)